# How to fetch shared data once using Svelte

Tags: svelte

I want to load static data only once from an API -- when when my app loads, for example.  And be able to access that from nested components.

```
// App.svelte

<script>
  import TeamSelector from "./lib/TeamSelector.svelte";

  teams = []; 
  onMount(fetchTeams);
  
  async function fetchTeams() {
    const response = await fetch("http://endpoint/teams");
    teams = await response.json()
  }
</script>

<div>
  Select two opposing teams: 

  Team 1: <TeamSelector/>
  Team 2: <TeamSelector/>
</div>
```

And then refer to that data elsewhere, without duplicating.
When I create multiple TeamSelector components for example

```
// TeamSelector.svelte

<script>
  export let teams; // can I get this from parent without passing as an attribute?
</script>

<select>
  {#each teams as team}
  <option value={team}>{team}</option>
  {/each}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `teams` to a [`writable`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-writable) store and make it available as a context via [`setContext`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext) (has to happen at the top level, not in the `onMount` function). You then can get it anywhere in the descendants using [`getContext`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-getcontext).

Making it a store is necessary to preserve reactivity.

E.g.

```js
  // ...
  const teams = writable([]);
  setContext('teams', teams);

  onMount(fetchTeams);
  
  async function fetchTeams() {
    // ...
    teams.set(await response.json());
  }
```

```html
<script>
  // ...
  const teams = getContext('teams');
</script>

<select>
  {#each $teams as team}
    <!-- ... -->
  {/each}
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks.  It appears that what I needed to do was reference teams with $: ```{#each $teams as team}``` -- I'm curious to know why that is.

Comment: Because it is a store. Stores work via a `subscribe` function. Via `$` syntax Svelte takes care of subscribing to the store and removing the subscription automatically when the component is destroyed.

Comment: See also [the documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values).

Comment: @fijiaaron Did that answer you question?